# What's the point of calling next() after res.send() in Resitfy?

Tags: node.js, restify

I am familiar with Express but new to Restify. Restify's document has many examples calling `next()` after `res.send()` as below:

```
server.get('/echo/:name', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send(req.params);
  return next();
});
```

This looks like a recommended pattern by some Restify experts as well:

[The consequences of not calling next() in restify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354850/the-consequences-of-not-calling-next-in-restify)

What's the real use case of doing this? After you call `res.send()`, is there anything a handler next in the chain can do?

Comment: well, of course, it could potentially do extra DB work or request tracking, etc. but... if you aren't doing any of that, why would you call .next? Doing so would allow future handlers that you add to work without you going back, and since there's no real harm in calling .next anyway, you might as well, just know that if multiple routes happen to match the same request, only one of them can successfully call `res.send`, the second would result in error.

Comment: @Kevin B: Thanks for your answer. That's the case of 'post-render' type middleware, right? Please read my opinion below and let me know what you think.

Comment: Correct. and i agree with your conclusion, only do so if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

After I did some more research, I think I found an answer.

Only practical use case of calling `next()` after `res.send()` is when you want to install 'post-render' type middlewares to catch all transactions after route handers finish their job.

In other cases, it simply adds unnecessary overhead for every and each request because it scans the rest of routes to find a next match.

Most middlewares are 'pre-render' type, which don't need `next()` call anyway. Even for post-render type middlewares, depending on voluntary calls of `next()` is simply too risky. You'd rather want to use more error-proof method like https://github.com/jshttp/on-finished instead.

Calling `next()` after `res.send()` is a bad practice causing unnecessary overhead in most cases. It should be used only when it is absolutely needed and you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for this insight- I think it should be pointed out that in particular if you're using any timing or logging behaviour then it's likely you *always* need `next()` called after `send()` - performance overhead or not. So if you're a library author reading this.. be polite and call `next()` so that you don't unintentionally break people's apps when they import your module.